# Calling $this inside Model in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I need reanimate an old site, that was made by another programmer a long time ago. The site is built on Phalcon and I don't know which versions of PHP are supported.

I'm seeing many errors like:

> Using $this when not in object context

It is triggered because in Models many functions calls core functions of Phalcon like `$this->session->get('auth')`, but it looks like a new version of PHP doesn't allow it.

How can I fix it without a total rewrite of all models?

Is there any other way to call Phalcon's `$this` in Model?

Or is it not possible?

Comment: Share an example of your model where you're calling `$this->session->get('auth')`. Sounds like you're calling it from a static method

Answer (score 1):

If you add variable `$di` (factory) to your application

you need to write this :

```
$this->di->session->get('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a static method, therefore an object has not been created and there IS NO $this.

Static methods are BAD, try and avoid! They're essentially standalone functions hiding inside a class. They're also very annoying to test.